Not having access to the phone's storage memory after updating Flutter's sdktarget to 34
Since I changed the sdk target of the app to 34.  The program no longer has access to the phone's storage.
I use the hive database.
I also gave him all the manifest permissions, including
read, write, manage, media, photo, video, audio
But again it doesn't have access and even when I make a request, it doesn't show that the user has given permission.  For this reason, it does not create the data folder of the program at all in data android.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE "/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>



var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
if (status.isGranted) {

  return;
} else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied){
 
  openAppSettings();
 
}

